# How to Remove Watermark from PDF using Python, without converting PDF to images in intermediate stage

Tags: python, pdf, python-camelot

I have the PDF file having watermark on it.It looks like follows:
[image]

I want to remove the watermark from the PDF file using python. I have tested existed solution on internet such as using PyPDF4.But that doesn't works for me. What I want to do is remove watermark and the apply some extraction task on PDF. My extraction task is to get the tabular data from PDF. For that purpose I am using camelot-py.Here, We shouldn't convert PDF to images and back to PDF because we couldn't extract the contents in PDF using pdf readers like camelot-py or tabula. PDF file is attached [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15fJnJBzG6b_QqPtTLgRLVYE4WJI5M8KN/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my use case is to remove the watermark from the PDF only, without affecting the structure of the PDF.

Comment: Ok, I have seen your attached output. That looks fine. But I have large number of such files and I want to make the program to do that. Could you please help me to do it programmatically with Python? It will be very helpful for me.